# Converting batch to sh

Tags: batch-file, sh

I need these two files converted to sh.
How do I do it?

File 1:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javac.exe" -cp . -d ./bin/ ./DavidScape/*.java
```

File 2:

```
@echo off
cd ../bin
color 0a
Title DavidScape 508
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe" DavidScape/Server 43594
pause
```

Comment: Both are identical, copy/paste error?

Comment: Sorry.. they're two different files but they both perform the same function. 
One compiles the RSPS and one runs the server.

But, yes, they are the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the long fugly Windows path name which ends with `javac.exe` with just `javac`.

You might need to adjust the `PATH` if the `javac` binary is in a nonstandard location (in which case the error message will be `javac: command not found` or something like that).

Your script should start with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line.
So:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PATH=$PATH:something maybe?
javac -cp . -d ./bin ./DavidScape/*.java
```

You will perhaps need to copy the `bin` and `DavidScape` directories into place as well.

You should not need to have two separate files with identical contents. Just reuse the same file.

Comment: Thank you. the #path=$path:something maybe? is where I put the java path, right?
Replacing "something maybe?"

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary but if it is, then uncomment and adapt that, yes. Note that `PATH` needs to be uppercase.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I found out what I did wrong. 
I did past the wrong code .-.
Give me a second to find the second one.

Comment: @echo off
cd ../bin
color 0a
Title DavidScape 508
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe" DavidScape/Server 43594
pause

I assume it'd be easy to just readapt your code to fit my needs?

Comment: @tripeleee
when I run the .sh this comes up:
(using SSH to connect)

    -bash: ./compile.sh: Permission denied
or
    -bash: ./compile.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to `chmod +x ./compile.sh` and the file needs to have Unix line endings (no DOS carriage returns / ^M:s).

Comment: Update your question to include the proper second script. Or actually post a new question instead.

Comment: when I did 'chmod +x ./compile.sh' I got 'bash: ./compile.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory'

Comment: Fix the line endings. Post a new question.

Comment: Fixed the first error. Now I get another one. Yey.
    [root@resinscape cmd]# ./compile.sh
    javac: file not found: ./DavidScape/*.java
    Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: You didn't copy over the DavidScape directory and its files.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
instead of using: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javac.exe", try setting JAVA_HOME variable or add bin to PATH system variable, then only invoke javac

**Second:**
then both .sh and .bat files looks the same:

```
javac -cp . -d ./bin/ ./DavidScape/*.java
```